# Trouble localizing iOS application, clarification needed

Tags: ios, localization

Please let me know what in the following sequence is incorrect.

- Somewhere in code, i have `self.label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"TITLE", nil);`
- Localizable.strings created ( `new -> Resource -> String file`)
- Localizable.strings (English) created // contains `"TITLE" = "Hello";`
- Localizable.strings (Russian) created // contains `"TITLE" = "Привет";`
- Simulator started and application deployed
- Xcode closed
- Simulator settings changed from English to Russian (`Settings -> General -> International -> Language -> Russian`)
- Xcode opened
- Application deployed (icon labels appear in Russian) .. when ran it says "Hello" instead of "Привет"

Am i missing a step? Did i do something in the wrong order? Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those steps look fine. Things to try:

1. The folder name for Russian needs to match the language code
   (ru.lproj -> Localizable.strings)
2. Check that the label is hooked up properly (if you're using interface builder) and not nil when you are setting self.label.text

Comment: Hmm ... you are right about the folder name , but Xcode created the folder `ru-RU.lpoj`, which is why (i guess) it did not work the first time. Interesting ..